# how do i solve this: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium

***this is the error am getting***

```
36 value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table["+str(r)+"]/tbody/tr["+str(c)+"]').text


AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

am trying to get a table that looks like this

Teams                         1st Goal  HT  FT
Manchester Blue vs. West Ham    1:0    2:0  3:0
London Guns vs. Watford         1:0    1:0  3:0
Liverpool vs. Leicester         0:1    1:2  2:2
Newcastle vs. Crystal Palace    1:0    1:0  2:1
Tottenham vs. Burnley           0:1    0:1  2:1
Chelsea vs. Bournemouth         1:0    2:0  2:2
Southampton vs. Wolverhampton   1:0    0:0  2:1
Manchester Reds vs. Everton     0:1    0:1  0:2

Comment: It looks like the function you're using returns a list of elements from a given page. Do you want to get the `text` attribute from each of these elements?

Comment: am trying to get a table that looks like this

Comment: So is the `value` list empty then? Have you made the change I suggested in my answer below to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to access the `text` attribute from each of the elements returned by `find_elements_by_xpath`. To see these, you have to do something like:

```py
# Create list of matching elements
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div[2]/table["+str(r)+"]/tbody/tr["+str(c)+"]')

# Read text attribute from each element
for elt in elements:
    print(elt.text)
```

Comment: I see. That probably has something to do with the expression you're using to find the table on the page. I'd mark this question as closed and then open a new one about the correct way to scrape the page for tables.

Comment: okay. thanks  thats what i will do

Comment: Based, just what I needed